# Combine attribute to use for ebay products in m2e pro

Tags: attributes, m2e

i am using magento 1.9.0.1 and i am listing items on ebay using magento extension called m2e pro.

as a description to show in ebay i am using attribute "description" but with that the problem is, it only list value of long description.

i want to list long description and specification as well. for that i need to make an attribute which has both of these values, but only for use in m2e pro not to display on front end of website etc.

can any one help me to achieve this please?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to push to eBay more than just the "description" attribute. If so, that's easy.

On your "Description Policy" for the "Description Source" you can have a "Custom Description". In there it is plain HTML with tags in the form of `#description#` to tell M2E Pro to inject the attribute values.

On my site we have this in our description:

```
                <div class="block-title">
                    <span>#name#</span></div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <div class="product-img">
                        <img alt="" src="#thumbnail#" /></div>
                    <div class="product-desc">
                        #description#<!-- separate -->#ebay_description_extra#</div>
                    <div style="clear: left;">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Or, as a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You can insert as many attributes as you like.

Is this what you need or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward approach, and based on the experience of sites which are using the M2e module this appears to be the standard approach.

Create a new Store View and name it something sensible e.g. "E-Bay Products"

Now when you edit the product you can have your main store (ie when you got onto www.example.com/product.html) it will load from this view. M2e is then configured to pull data from the E-Bay Products store.

All your product which you wish to display on E-Bay need to be in this store and you will configure the description to have the content which you wish. Using this architecture you have two separate descriptions maintained independently from each other.

As an alternative approach, if you are unable to do this for any reason, and this would not be the strategy recommended you could modify the module such that when its retrieving the product description to send over to eBay, you insert additional markup based on other attributes automatically.